# CMake if statement evaluated in makefile

Tags: if-statement, makefile, cmake

Standard cmake if() else() statement is evaluated during cmake execution. Is it possible to put if/else to makefile by declaring it in CMakeLists.txt ?

Comment: How would this help you build your software? Can you give an explicit example?

Comment: Not directly.  But there are ways to express various build-time  conditionals.  Specifics needed.

Comment: Yeah this is a x vs y problem. Your question should be "How do I conditionally do X at build time" rather than the question above. The `if() else()` control statements in the CMakeList.txt are only run at generation time, but 99% of the time the "if else" you want at build time is really just at generation time...

Answer (score 0):

CMake can be run in "process script" and "command" modes (see [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/manual/cmake.1.html) for `-P` and `-E` flags). You can utilize this to create custom target, which would call `cmake` to do desired tasks.

This target would end up in Makefile, so you will be able to execute it without running `cmake` in the build dir.